# why I don't always get ItemElementName in wsdl+xsd code generation from choice-element with WSCF blue?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, code-generation, wscf.blue

I use WSCF blue to generate web service code from wsdl. Sometimes choice-element in xsd is generated to Item and ItemElementName. Sometimes just Item. Couldn't find any logic in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it that there must be choice-elements of same type in schema. E.g. 2 int choices or 2 string choices so it can't be known anymore only by type. In my example had three different types in choice -> no ItemElementName enumeration and property.